# How with Auth::loginUsingId in seeder to set spatie/permission access?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-permission

On laravel 9 site I fill some init data in seeders
and I use line :

```
Auth::loginUsingId($defaultAdminId);
```

and in model_has_permissions table I have a row referenced $defaultAdminId and Admin
permission in permissions table

But later checking is logged is admin

```
if ( Auth::user()->can(ACCESS_ADMIN) ) {   // Is Admin
    ...
```

The checks above does not work . I suppose method Auth::loginUsingId( does not know anything about
model_has_permissions table . If there is a way to set spatie/permission access after calling Auth::loginUsingId( ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.26.1",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5.5"
"laravel/passport": "^10.4.1",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a decision with code :

```
Auth::user()->load('permissions');
```

on login.